# CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange Incorrectly Counting Spaces at End of String?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I'm working with `CoreText` and I notice that `CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange` incorrectly counts spaces at the end of the string which are NOT visible in the frame as being visible. FYI, I am adding the space as a string @" " using `insertAttributedString` to the end of my `NSMutableAttributedString`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

UPDATE: Still haven't found a solution to this, is this the intended behavior? Or this just a bug?

Comment: You can find the width of whitespace at the end of a CTLine using CTLineGetTrailingWhitespaceWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. To work around this replace the " " at the end of the string with something else, do whatever you need to do, then reinsert the " " at the end.