# Invalid Unicode characters in XCode

Tags: xcode, unicode

I am trying to put Unicode characters (using a custom font) into a string which I then display using Quartz, but XCode doesn't like the escape codes for some reason, and I'm really stuck.

```
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, 15, 15, "\u0066", 1);
```

It doesn't like this (Latin lowercase f) and says it is an "invalid universal character".

```
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, 15, 15, "\ue118", 1);
```

It doesn't complain about this but displays nothing. When I open the font in FontForge, it shows the glyph as there and valid. Also Font Book validated the font just fine. If I use the font in TextEdit and put in the Unicode character with the character viewer Unicode table, it appears just fine. Just Quartz won't display it.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: try an upper case E... e.g. "`\uE118`"

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237565/iphone-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-for-japanese-characters

Comment: @trojanfoe's link is good. CGContextShowTextAtPoint isn't very flexible (it can have trouble displaying even simple depending on the font). See http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/May/msg00593.html.

Comment: Thank you! I got it kind of working. Using CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(context, 15, 15, (const CGGlyph *)"4", 1); but the symbols I use in the string don't match up with the font. All numbers 0 - 9 and then lowercase then uppercase alphabets go through most of the font in the order of the glyphs (not the matching characters though) but I don't know how to get the other glyphs to show up. For example "0" shows U+E119 and "1" shows U+E11A

Comment: I also still have the problem of it saying that some characters are invalid which is very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the font to use standard alphanumeric characters in the end. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid universal character" error is [due to the definition in C99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147811/349112): Essentially `\uNNNN` escapes are supposed to allow one programmer to call a *variable* `føø` and another programmer (who might not be able to type ø) to refer to it as `f\u00F8\u00F8`. To make parsing easier for everyone, you can't use a `\u` escape for a control character or a character that is in the "basic character set" (perhaps a lesson learned from [Java's unicode escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) which can do crazy things like ending comments).

The second error is probably because `"\ue118"` is getting compiled to the UTF-8 sequence `"\xee\x8e\x98"` — three `char`s. `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()` assumes that one `char` (byte) is one glyph, and `CGContextSelectFont()` only supports the encodings `kCGEncodingMacRoman` (which decodes the bytes to "Óéò") and `kCGEncodingFontSpecific` (what happens is anyone's guess. The docs say not to use `CGContextSetFont()` (which does not specify the char-to-glyph mapping) in conjunction with `CGContextShowText()` or `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()`.

If you know the glyph number, you can use `CGContextShowGlyphs()`, `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint()`, or `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions()`.