# Print unicode hex code which is part of basic latin as a symbol in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a list containing a mix of symbols and unicode numbers (all of length four), of which some are part of basic latin. I want to print them all as symbols.

An example of my failed attempt using Bash (under Cygwin):

```
list="0 3 4 5 005e 0060 00ff"
$ for c in $list; do [[ ${#c} = 4 ]] && env printf "\\u$c\n" || echo $c; done
0
3
4
5
printf: invalid universal character name \u005e
005e
`
ÿ
```

I get the same problem regardless of locale and encoding in the terminal.

I can not get the answer for this problem from askununtu to work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20806/why-does-printf-report-an-error-on-all-but-three-ascii-range-unicode-codepoint

Comment: It's not suprising that `001b` doesn't work, since that's the escape character (what would it print?). `005e` does seem to be swallowed up  in whatever Byzantine handling is applied to the basic ASCII character set.

Comment: True! Good catch. I'll update. 005e though is 'CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT' which has the symbol '^'. So that still shows the problem.

Comment: This might be some old bug, you can check [this post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-05/msg00067.html). `005e` is one of the unicode with the issue. You could try to use `printf` instead of `env printf` i.e. not in new environment.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I've tried without env, in that case the unicode hex value is printed uninterpreted. Reading the discussion related to the bug report, they seem reluctant to identify it as a bug. Hm..

Comment: hmm all I can say is good luck! Maybe someone will come along and help ^^

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it by hand. It's a "one off" problem. If I needed to automate it I guess I'll resort to Python.

Comment: Re: "I've tried without env, in that case the unicode hex value is printed uninterpreted": That's because `env` is an external program, so `env printf ...` searches the path for an external `printf` program, whereas just `printf ...` invokes the built-in Bash `printf`, which doesn't support the `\uXXXX` notation. But anyway, despite what another.anon.coward's comment seems to say, `env` does *not* start with an empty environment, unless you run it with the `-i` (`--ignore-environment`) flag.

Comment: The very short answer is [because it parses it like C99/C++98](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144885/inserting-unicode-hyphen-minus-into-string-causes-error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fix will let you use any characters in any encoding:

```
list="0 3 4 5 005e 0060 00ff"
for c in $list; do
    if [ ${#c} = 4 ]; then
        echo 0 "$c" | xxd -r | iconv -f UNICODEBIG -t UTF-8
        echo
    else
        echo "$c"
    fi
done
```

xxd with the -r option converts hex text into bytes.  It requires line numbers, which is what the leading 0 in the echo is.  xxd in this case outputs the two bytes indicated by c.

The result of xxd is piped to iconv.  iconv converts one encoding to another.  UNICODEBIG is two-byte unicode characters with the first byte most significant.  UTF-8 is the encoding to convert to.  (Substitute your terminal's encoding if you don't use UTF-8).  This converts the character into the specified encoding.

This trick gives you complete freedom to encode any unicode character from 0000 to ffff in any encoding that supports it.

EDIT: Found an easier way using xxd.  The new way is shown above, the old way is here:

```
echo -ne \\x"${c:0:2}"\\x"${c:2:2}" | iconv -f UNICODEBIG -t UTF-8
```

Comment: I guess I have been confused about endianness all my life.  Big endian = most significant byte first.  That makes sense with this example.

Comment: Great job and nice example! Thanks!!

Comment: +1 and I wish I could plus your answer a few more times! Given that I don't use bash scripts often, this problem was driving me nuts for the last 20 minutes: bash `printf` would treat most `\uXXXX` correctly, while producing bogus results for some. Thanks a lot for a quick fix!